# Libgdx Assertion Failed [Expression: pointCount > 0]

Tags: java, android, libgdx, runtime-error, assertion

I am currently developing a multiplayer game with AI on android using LibGDX. But now I encountered a problem, when I run it on desktop twice or thrice that are connected to each other through UDP and TCP with different ports respectively. After a few minutes of playing one of them becomes unresponsive. I have a few tests on android but I'm not sure if the crash will appear. After I hit "Close program", some details appear on Android Studio console logs. I have no idea why it happens.

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Assertion failed!

Program: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe
File: /var/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/libgdx/extensions/gdx-box2d/gdx-box2d/jni/Box2D/Dynamics/Contacts/b2ContactSolver.cpp, Line 73

Expression: pointCount > 0
```

I used multi-threading, synchronization, array list of objects with com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body that are synchronized.

[Three desktop apps are connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7TQs.jpg)

[One desktop app becomes unresponsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjq1S.png)

UPDATE : After using jstack for debugging, I found out that this line causes to malfunction randomly. I think I used box2d body improperly.

```
world.step(ScreenManager.deltaTime, 6, 2);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is quite difficult for the users to answer your question without looking at your code. So you might want to add some snippet.

Comment: I think it's generally bad idea to manipulate state of gui objects from different threads. you should queue up you transformations from network threads and then apply them with your gui thread on the next act/draw/frame.

Comment: @Nonika that's exactly what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The isSensor from FixtureDef must not be changed during contacts of bodies, 
because there are possibilities of assertion failure.